# UIViewController Container subcontroller animations

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I've created my own split view controller for the iPad.  My main purpose in creating my own is to allow the user to open/close the left pain at will.  The problem I'm having is I can't find a way to get the view controllers in my right pain to animate the changes.  I animate the views in my split view controller, but all other sub view controllers in the right pane don't animate their views.  I'm not switching views, so I can't use any of those methods and I'm not changing orientations, so those methods are out (although, I did try them anyway but it didn't work).  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Currently, my code to initiate the animations is:

```
- (void) setShowLeftPane:(BOOL)showLeftPane{
    if (_showLeftPane != showLeftPane){
        _showLeftPane = showLeftPane;

        //Alert viewcontrollers and perform animation
        if (showLeftPane) [_leftController viewWillAppear:YES];
        else [_leftController viewWillDisappear:YES];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{ 
            [self layoutViews];
            [_rightController viewWillLayoutSubviews];
        } completion:^(BOOL fin){
            [_rightController viewDidLayoutSubviews];
            if (_showLeftPane) [_leftController viewDidAppear:YES];
            else [_leftController viewDidDisappear:YES];
        }];

        //Switch out the appropriate pane button view
        [_showLeftPane ? _openLeftPane : _closeLeftPane removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:_showLeftPane ? _closeLeftPane : _openLeftPane];
    }
}
```

Currently my right pane view controller is a UINavigationController, so I'm dealing with a stock class.  I've considered adding a category method `viewWillAnimateSubviewLayoutWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)interval` to UINavigationController that will cycle through it's view controllers testing for/sending that same method to it's view controllers so that they can perform their animations, but that's not quite ideal especially if there's a way to use stock methods.

I'm considering writing my own NavigationController but that's a lot of work I don't want to do if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that care, I ended up writing my own Navigation Container Controller.  It was a lot of work, but it ended up being ideal for a few reasons.  First, creating the custom container controller gave me a much more intimate understanding of how view controllers work, which has been helpful.  Second, it gave me much more control over the how the 'navigation controller' works, allowing me to easily implement custom transitions and custom pop/push methods, including a 'replace' (pop, then push) method that was sorely needed in my application.